# 'str' object has no attribute 'get' attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I solve it...

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:\Monu\Work\python\PROJECT\New folder\LMS.py", line 262, in onDoubalclick
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `TRANSECTION` WHERE Book_Id=?",(val1.get(),))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I already convert it in string or integer but not working

```
def onDoubalclick(event):
    test=treeview.item(treeview.selection())
    print(test)
    items=treeview.selection()[0]
    val1=str(treeview.item(items)['values'][0])
    print(type(val1))    
    popsearch()
    DataBase()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `TRANSECTION` WHERE Book_Id=?",(val1.get(),))
    info=cursor.fetchall()
    for ROW1 in info:
        print(rows)
        treeview2.insert("",END,value=ROW1)
```

I want to get a value that stores in `val1` and search that value in the database

Comment: `val1` is a string. What are you expecting `val1.get()` to return?

Comment: I want how to solve  AttributeError

Comment: *You're* calling `val1.get()`. You must be expecting `val1.get()` to do something or there's no reason to call it. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @user10532514 let me rephrase khelwood's question. `val1` IS a string. Strings have no `.get()` methods, and that's why you get this error. So :  __why__ do you think you have to call `.get()` on a string to get it's value ? A string IS it's own value already.

Comment: how I can call val1.

Comment: Can you show the output of this program? For instance I would be interested in the type of the `val1` variable. The simple solution is just to remove the `get()` function/method call on the `val1` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct Strings do not have a get attribute.

This is the easiest way to prevent this error from crashing your program. I just removed the `get()` function/method call from the `val1` variable.

```
def onDoubalclick(event):
    test=treeview.item(treeview.selection())
    print(test)
    items=treeview.selection()[0]
    val1=str(treeview.item(items)['values'][0])
    print(type(val1))    
    popsearch()
    DataBase()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `TRANSECTION` WHERE Book_Id=?",(val1,))
    info=cursor.fetchall()
    for ROW1 in info:
        print(rows)
        treeview2.insert("",END,value=ROW1)
```

Another option is to not fix the error but surround the bug in a try/except block to prevent the program from crashing.

So as an example you could do the following:

```
#more code above left off to keep things simple

try:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `TRANSECTION` WHERE Book_Id=?", (val1.get(),))
    info=cursor.fetchall()
    #the rest of your code

except Exception as e:
    print "This exception was thrown: %s" % str(e)

#the rest of your code
print "Blah. Print stuff here. Print variable state. Print time."
```